# Replacing wrong country name with the correct one in dataset

Tags: python

[Sample Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVUNo.png)
i am facing an issue and don't know how to approach it.
i have a large dataset with two coulmn i.e country and cityname. There are multiple entries where country and  City names are Spelled incorrect due to human error. eg England is written as Egnald

Can anybody please guide me how to check and correct them in python?

i was able to found the incorrect entries by using the code below, but i am not sure how to correct them with the proper one with automated process as i cannot do it manually

Thanks

Here is what i have done so far:

```
import pycountry as pc

#converting billing country to lower string
df['Billing Country'].str.lower()

input_country_list=list(df['Billing Country'])
input_country_list=[element.upper() for element in input_country_list];
def country_name_check():
pycntrylst = list(pc.countries)
alpha_2 = []
alpha_3 = []
name = []
common_name = []
official_name = []
invalid_countrynames =[]
tobe_deleted = ['IRAN','SOUTH KOREA','NORTH KOREA','SUDAN','MACAU','REPUBLIC 
OF IRELAND']
for i in pycntrylst:
    alpha_2.append(i.alpha_2)
    alpha_3.append(i.alpha_3)
    name.append(i.name)
    if hasattr(i, "common_name"):
        common_name.append(i.common_name)
    else:
        common_name.append("")
    if hasattr(i, "official_name"):
        official_name.append(i.official_name)
    else:
        official_name.append("")
for j in input_country_list:
    if j not in map(str.upper,alpha_2) and j not in map(str.upper,alpha_3) 
and j not in map(str.upper,name) and j not in map(str.upper,common_name) and 
j not in map(str.upper,official_name):
        invalid_countrynames.append(j)
invalid_countrynames = list(set(invalid_countrynames))
invalid_countrynames = [item for item in invalid_countrynames if item not in 
tobe_deleted]
return print(invalid_countrynames)
```

By running the above code i was able to get the names of misspelled country name, can anyone please guide how to replace them with the correct one now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SequenceMatcher` from `difflib` ([see here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html)). It has `ratio()` method, that allows you to compare similarity of two strings (higher number means higher similarity, 1.0 means same words):

```
>>> from difflib import SequenceMatcher
>>> SequenceMatcher(None,'Dog','Cat').ratio()
0.0
>>> SequenceMatcher(None,'Dog','Dogg').ratio()
0.8571428571428571
>>> SequenceMatcher(None,'Cat','Cta').ratio()
0.6666666666666666
```

My idea is to have list of correct names of countries, and compare each record in your dataframe to each item in this list, and select the most similar, thus you should get the correct name of country. Then you can put it into the function, and apply this function over all records in your Country column in dataframe:

```
>>> #let's say we have following dataframe
>>> df
   number  country
0       1  Austria
1       2  Autrisa
2       3   Egnald
3       4   Sweden
4       5  England
5       6  Swweden
>>>
>>> #let's specify correct names
>>> correct_names = {'Austria','England','Sweden'}
>>>
>>> #let's specify the function that select most similar word
>>> def get_most_similar(word,wordlist):
...     top_similarity = 0.0
...     most_similar_word = word
...     for candidate in wordlist:
...         similarity = SequenceMatcher(None,word,candidate).ratio()
...         if similarity > top_similarity:
...             top_similarity = similarity
...             most_similar_word = candidate
...     return most_similar_word
...
>>> #now apply this function over 'country' column in dataframe
>>> df['country'].apply(lambda x: get_most_similar(x,correct_names))
0    Austria
1    Austria
2    England
3     Sweden
4    England
5     Sweden
Name: country, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. its very detailed and helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
df.replace(['Egnald', 'Cihna'], ['England', 'China'])
```

This will find and replace in the entire DF

Use `df.replace(['Egnald', 'Cihna'], ['England', 'China'], inplace=True)` if you want to do this inplace.